# objective-c primitive arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, primitive

I want to have a mutable array with primitives in obj-c (selectors). What's the recommended way to do this? `NSArray` and those can only hold objects.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539017/nsarray-with-c-types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an `NSValue` to wrap the selector or any other primitive type you need. In Cocoa SEL is some kind of pointer, so you can use `[NSValue valueWithPointer:whatever]` to construct it and `[value pointerValue]` to get it out. Or, in general you can use `[NSValue valueWithBytes:&whatever objCType:@encode(SEL)]`; this works for any type.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about NSValue.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to store an array of `SEL` objects, the easiest thing would be to convert the `SEL`s to `NSString`s using the `NSStringFromSelector()` function, store them in an `NSMutableArray`, and then convert them back to `SEL`s when you pull them out using `NSSelectorFromString()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Other than managing a C-style array yourself (which is definitely not the best option, IMO), your only option is to use `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`, and store the numbers using `NSNumber`. It's slightly more annoying to get the value out than with the actual numeric type, but it does free you from managing the array's memory yourself.

Comment: Actually, what I want to store is a SEL. What type is that, really?

Answer (score 0):

Since the primitive types are generally just numbers (be they integer or floating-point) or pointers, what's the problem with using the classes used to wrap those up for your purposes?  An `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumbers`, for example?