# Releasing path with CGPathRelease causing BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a CGMutablePathRef property in a subclassed UIImageview.  When I create a new path and assign it to the property, CGPathRelease causes an error when I call CGPathContainsPoint.  IF I don't release the path the code works fine but there is a leak. How do I properly transfer ownership and release?

```
.h // UIImageView subclass
@property CGMutablePathRef pathHold;


.m
CGMutablePathRef myPath;
myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect myRect2 = holderImageView.bounds;
float midX = CGRectGetMidX(myRect2);
float midY = CGRectGetMidY(myRect2);

CGAffineTransform t = 
CGAffineTransformConcat(
                        CGAffineTransformConcat(
                                                CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-midX, -midY), 
                                                     CGAffineTransformMakeScale(holderImageView.pathZone,holderImageView.pathZone)), 
                        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(midX, midY));
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(myPath, &t, myRect2);
CGPathCloseSubpath(myPath);

[holderImageView setPathHold:myPath];
CGPathRelease(myPath); // If path not released, works fine but leak.  
[self addSubview:holderImageView];
[holderImageView release];


.m
if(CGPathContainsPoint (self.pathHold, NULL, touchLocation, FALSE )) // This Causes error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your property without the (retain) attribute. It means, when you're assigning the path to this property, the runtime only does a pointer assignment and does not -retain your path, thus when you CGPathRelease() the path reference, it gets deallocated. So, you must declare the the property on the placeholder image class like this:

```
@property (retain) id pathHold;
```

and then assign it like this:

```
[holderImageView setPathHold:(id)myPath];
```

Please note that in the declaration I used 'id' as type. That's because almost any CoreGraphics and CoreFoundation type is in fact a valid Objective-C object, so this conversion (toll-free bridging) can be done and the type casting is only needed to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer and helped me on many fronts.  I wasn't exactly sure how to properly retain this. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: NP ;-) It's worth keeping in mind that CF* and CG* structures are all of type 'id', it WILL help you a lot.

Comment: As a minor point, it's not that the Core Foundation types are valid Objective-C objects, but that the base CFType is bridged to NSObject, as Mike Ash explains here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-22-toll-free-bridging-internals.html , and Ken Ferry mentions in his answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1539634/19679 .

Comment: I'm not sure about this. CFType is defined as void *, and it's not the case that CoreFoundation types are subclasses of CFType (as there's no subclassing in C). Every struct CFWhatever * has intentionally the same memory layout (that is, they all begin with a Class pointer).

Comment: @H2CO3 are you sure? I just tried this with CGPoint and CGRect, and it doesn't appear to work. Looking at the header files, they appear to lack the CFTypeID stuff that the main CFType things possess?

Comment: If I try to cast a CGPoint, I get: "error: Semantic Issue: Operand of type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') where arithmetic or pointer type is required"

Comment: But CGPoint and CGRect are *NOT* CoreFoundation types. They're just normal structs, therefore you can't cast them to (pointer-typed) objects. Similarly, that's why there is NO CGPointCreate or CGPointRelease functions. They're not objects.