# Optimize CGContextDrawRadialGradient in drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, drawrect

In my iPad app, I have a UITableView that alloc/inits a UIView subclass every time a new cell is selected. I've overridden `drawRect:` in this UIView to draw a radial gradient and it works fine, but performance is suffering - when a cell is tapped, the UIView takes substantially longer to draw a gradient programmatically as opposed to using a .png for the background. Is there any way to "cache" my `drawRect:` method or the gradient it generates to improve performance? I'd rather use `drawRect:` instead of a .png. My method looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     size_t gradLocationsNum = 2;
     CGFloat gradLocations[2] = {0.0f, 1.0f};
     CGFloat gradColors[8] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f}; 
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
     CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradColors, gradLocations, gradLocationsNum);
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     CGPoint gradCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
     float gradRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width , self.bounds.size.height) ;

     CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, gradRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

     CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can render graphics into a context and then store that as a UIImage. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878141/is-it-possible-to-draw-graphics-with-cgcontext-and-save-them-into-a-nsmutablearr) should get you started:

> `drawRect:` is a method on `UIView` used to draw the view itself, not to pre-create graphic objects.
>
> Since it seems that you want to create shapes to store them and draw later, it appears reasonable to create the shapes as `UIImage` and draw them using `UIImageView`. `UIImage` can be stored directly in an `NSArray`.
>
> To create the images, do the following (on the main queue; not in drawRect:):
>
> 1) create a bitmap context
>
> ```
> UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale);
> ```
>
> 2) get the context
>
> ```
> CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
> ```
>
> 3) draw whatever you need
>
> 4) export the context into an image
>
> ```
> UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
> ```
>
> 5) destroy the context
>
> ```
> UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
> ```
>
> 6) store the reference to the image
>
> ```
> [yourArray addObject:image];
> ```
>
> Repeat for each shape you want to create.
>
> For details see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for the above mentioned functions. To get a better understanding of the difference between drawing in `drawRect:` and in arbitrary place in your program and of working with contexts in general, I would recommend you read the [Quartz2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html), especially the section on Graphics Contexts.

Comment: There’s no highlighting hint for Objective-C, as far as I can tell. Will plain C work?

Comment: I have seen the error of my ways, and will repent :) (thanks for the edit)