# Animate Center of Radial Gradient

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

How can I animate the center of a radial gradient as drawn in a custom CA Layer:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
return self;
}

 - (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

size_t gradLocationsNum = 2;
CGFloat gradLocations[2] = {0.0f, 1.0f};
CGFloat gradColors[8] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f};
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradColors, gradLocations, gradLocationsNum);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGPoint gradCenter= CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
float gradRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width , self.bounds.size.height) ;

CGContextDrawRadialGradient (ctx, gradient, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, gradRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);


CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924839/668518)

Is there any way to move the center of a radial gradient drawn in this fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You may generate a timer or rather a display link to trigger a refresh method on every frame.

When you start animating you should save the current point to some property (`self.animationStartPoint`) and save the target point to some property (`self.animationEndPoint`). Then save the 2 dates you want the animation between like `self.animationStartDate = [NSDate date]` and `self.animationDate = [self.animationStartDate byAddingTimeInterval:animationDuration]`. Now when timer or display link fires you need to only call `[self setNeedsDisplay]`.

In draw method you now need to interpolate the two points. First we need to check where in animation time are we:

```
CGFloat scale = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince:self.animationStartDate] / [self.animationEndDate timeIntervalSince:self.animationStartDate];
```

While animating the scale should be between 0 and 1. If it is less than the animation is still waiting (if you use "after delay" procedure). If it is greater than the animation is over:

```
if(scale < 0.0) return;
else if(scale > 1.0) {
   scale = 1.0;
   // TODO: report animation completed, invalidate timer or display link
}
```

Then use the scale to find the current point:

```
CGPoint gradCenter = CGPointMake(self.animationStartPoint.x + (self.animationEndPoint.x - self.animationStartPoint.x)*scale, self.animationStartPoint.y + (self.animationEndPoint.y - self.animationStartPoint.y)*scale);
```